# How to serialize a postgres column in ruby on rails correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, serialization

I'm trying to save to a column which has a datatype of 'string', within a postgres db using ruby on rails. Say I want to save an integer to this column. Is there any way to serialize the saved data in a way to automatically fetch the contents of the column as an integer, without having to call 'string_value'.to_i function on it?

Comment: Why? If you are working with integers stick with a integer column.

Comment: As Adrian said above. Is value of this column always an int? Change it to int. If you don't want to then there's no way to do it without defining a method using `to_i`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Let me clarify; I'm trying to see if the column could be serialized as either a string, integer, or any other datatype due to a business requirement. I thought perhaps there would be a way to pass in a hash or something ( looking like : { 'datatype':'String', 'value':'some value' }. Obviously I could pass in a string of the hash and just evaluate it after, but I was just asking if there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: "...I'm trying to see if the column could be serialized as either a string, integer, or any other datatype due to a business requirement..." -- That smells like a bad design.

Comment: while you could [`serialize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) your column, sounds to me like you need a whole separate table(s) for your logic.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to aware that storing serialized information may complicate filtering, sorting and requesting the data.

But if that is your plan, the best idea is to store that column of a different data type than string.

You can do st like this:

```
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  # serialize
  serialize :your_column_name, Hash

  # Optional
  def set_value_as_hash(data_type, value)
    self.your_column_name = { datatype: data_type, value: value }
    save
  end

  # optional
  def get_value_from_hash
    value = self.your_column_name[:value]
    case self.your_column_name[:datatype]
    when 'Integer'
      value.to_i
    when 'String'
      value.to_s
    else
      value
    end
  end
end
```